# Discord.js: Fetch More than 100 Archived Threads

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been working on a Discord bot command to fetch all of the archived threads on a server. I'm currently running into the 100 limit and am looking for a way to get around that limit.

[Here's a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73313581/discord-js-fetch-archived-threads-from-specific-all-channels) I made previously and was able to get up to 100 threads fetched from that.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153125/fetch-more-than-100-messages) where they made a system to fetch more than 100 messages, but I haven't been able to successfully convert that into code to fetch more than 100 threads. Unfortunately, dates and orders have been a bit inconsistent when printing threads, so getting that data has been a challenge.

Here's the code that I have so far that's only fetching 100 threads:

```
client.on('messageCreate',  async function (message) {
    if(message.content === "!test"){
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("GUILD_ID_HERE"); // number removed for privacy reasons

    var textChannels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === ChannelType.GuildText);

    textChannels.forEach(async (channel, limit = 500) => {
                let archivedThreads = await channel.threads.fetchArchived({limit: 100});
                console.log(archivedThreads);
            });
    }
}
```

In my final code, I also am printing this to a text file rather than the console, but I've left that additional code out here to keep this code more simplified for debugging.

Any ideas on how I can iterate through and print multiple sets of 100 threads at a time to bypass the limitations?

Comment: It's a bit hard to fully grasp the issue, but if a core issue that things are arriving out of order it's because you used `forEach` with async/await. Convert it to a regular loop and if possible stop using `forEach` altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So right now the biggest issue is that I'm unable to print more than 100 threads from a channel. I haven't found a way to successfully print the thread data out using a regular loop instead of ```forEach```, so that's why I've been using it that way.

The data being out of order isn't as big of an issue, it just makes it hard for me to use the ```before:``` command that they recommended in the linked post for messages; and sometimes the dates print out strangely (i.e. Invalid Date or year 2494) so I haven't been able to successfully parse through them that way either.

Answer (score 0):

The function passed to `Array.forEach` does not awaits, you may use `for of` operator or classic `for` loop inside an async function to await on threads for synchronous execution.

```js
var textChannels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === ChannelType.GuildText);

async function fetchArchives(){
   for (const channel of textChannels) {
      let archivedThreads = await channel.threads.fetchArchived({limit: 100});
      console.log(archivedThreads);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that clarification on that! When I tried out this code though I get this error: ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetchArchived')```

Comment: Based on your error, looks like `channel.threads`  seems to be undefined

Comment: Hmm yeah. For some reason, it doesn't have this error when it's referenced in the ```forEach``` loop, but happens when it's converted to a ```for``` loop, which is where I've been kind of stuck with this. Do you have any ideas on why it seems to run without this error in the ```forEach``` code in my post, but has the error with this code?

Comment: Is this error for all threads or just for a particular thread? It would be safer to add a check before accessing threads since it could be undefined.

if(channel.threads){
      let archivedThreads = await channel.threads.fetchArchived({limit: 100});
      console.log(archivedThreads);
}

Comment: So I think the issue is that in the ```forEach``` code, I'm defining ```channel``` in the ```forEach``` function (similar to what we're doing in the ```for``` loop here). But for some reason, it's not undefined in the context of the ```forEach``` when it's used, but it is when it's used in the ```for``` loop. Sorry, I'm still new to JavaScript/Discord API so I'm not entirely sure why there's a difference between those. When I use the if statement you provided in the ```for``` loop from your code, it's undefined, but when I use it in the ```forEach``` loop from the original, it shows threads.